# Failing to produce via kafka-avro-console-producer

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I've prepared the Avro payload using the avro-tools as such:

```
avro-tools fromjson --schema-file foobar-schema.avsc foobar-input.json > foobar.avro
```

And when running the following command:

```
kafka-avro-console-producer \
--broker-list "foobar" \
--topic "foobar" \
--property schema.registry.basic.auth.credentials.source="USER_INFO" \
--property schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info="foobar:foobar" \
--property schema.registry.url="foobar" \
--property key.schema='{"type":"string"}' \
--property key.separator=":" \
--property value.schema.file=foobar-schema.avsc \
--property value.schema.registry.url="foobar" \
--property parse.key=true \
 < foobar.avro
```

I get:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing json Objavro.schema�{"type" to Avro of schema "string"
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageReader.readFrom(AvroMessageReader.java:127)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.readMessage(SchemaMessageReader.java:397)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:50)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Objavro': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"Obj\u0001\u0004\u0016avro.schema�\u0004{"type""; line: 1, column: 11]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2418)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:759)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:3038)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2079)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:805)
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.configure(JsonDecoder.java:124)
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.<init>(JsonDecoder.java:66)
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.<init>(JsonDecoder.java:74)
    at org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory.jsonDecoder(DecoderFactory.java:266)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchemaUtils.toObject(AvroSchemaUtils.java:281)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchemaUtils.toObject(AvroSchemaUtils.java:274)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageReader.readFrom(AvroMessageReader.java:120)
    ... 3 more
```

The schema foobar-schema.avsc is like that:

```
{
  "namespace": "com.some.namespace",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "SomeEvent",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "fieldOne",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "fieldTwo",
      "type": "double"
    },
    {
      "name": "fieldThree",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

And the input foobar-input.json is like that:

```
{"fieldOne":"987654321","fieldTwo": 250.75,"fieldThree":null}
```

I've checked that the Avro binary input is valid by converting it back to a JSON format - all looked good.
Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kafka-avro-console-producer` accepts line-delimited JSON input, not Avro files. The Avro conversion happens internally to that script, automatically, per the schema provided. (using Avro's JSON `DecoderFactory`)

You'll also want to remove `key.separator` and `parse.key` properties since the JSON that you shared has no "keys"

Comment: Thanks, I've followed your advice and now I've got past the errors. But I'm failing to produce with a 'topic timeout' error returned. I'll create another thread to address that. Thanks again!