# Failing to produce via kafka-avro-console-producer: "Topic foobar not present in metadata after 60000 ms."

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm failing to produce to an existing Kafka topic using the following command:

```
kafka-avro-console-producer \
--broker-list "foobar" \
--topic "foobar-topic" \
--property schema.registry.basic.auth.credentials.source="USER_INFO" \
--property schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info="foobar:foobar" \
--property schema.registry.url="foobar" \
--property key.schema='{"type":"string"}' \
--property value.schema.file=reversal.avsc \
--property value.schema.registry.url="foobar" \
 < foobar.json
```

I get this outputted 2x after running the above command and sending a valid structured message:

```
[2023-07-27 11:38:02,823] ERROR Error when sending message to topic foobar-topic with key: null, value: 24 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback:52)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic foobar-topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
[2023-07-27 11:38:02,823] ERROR Error when sending message to topic foobar-topic with key: null, value: 24 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback:52)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic foobar-topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

The topic is present, and has been tested previously via the "kafka-console-producer" command. Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thank you.

NB: This is a follow up question based on the outcome from: [Failing to produce via kafka-avro-console-producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76773567/failing-to-produce-via-kafka-avro-console-producer)

Comment: You have auth for the registry. Do you need auth for the brokers? I've seen this error when broker auth fails

Comment: Thanks, I will try providing credentials for the broker as well.

Comment: What are the property names for the broker? I'm failing to understand how they are mapped correctly for the CLI command.

Comment: It's for the producer, not the broker. Without knowing how your broker is configured, it's hard to answer that. Refer Kafka producer documentation, you'll see configs for both SASL and SSL options. For the CLI command, you'll need to provide `--producer.config` with a file where you can move all other properties into as well